# How to do parallel requests on a single Express endpoint?

Tags: express

Please consider the following code:

```
const app = require('express')();
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    await sleep(10000);
    res.send('done');
});
app.listen(9999);
```

I thought that I can fetch this endpoint in parallel, but apparently Express only processes one request at a time and serves the rest sequentially.

Why is this, and how can I make one endpoint able to handle multiple requests in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS (the underlying platform of express) is asynchronous but single-threaded. There is a single event loop executing statements. If you block CPU time for a long time, by sleeping like in this code, the thread isn't able to move to other statements (or service a new request) i.e. the server hangs. This is why NodeJS is not for CPU-blocking requests - those must be delegated to another system that is itself multi-threaded. IO requests like reading a file or using network for send/receive aren't a problem because they execute in the background without blocking the Node thread. For these, NodeJS simply registers a callback to be invoked when the background operation completes, and it can continue executing other statements (including servicing other requests).

So you can do parallel requests, but only if handling those requests doesn't block CPU.

Comment: I have a decent understanding of the asynchronous, single-threaded programming model of JavaScript (or so I thought). The thing I don't understand is how my code actually blocks the CPU. After all, promises are async. Or does the endpoint get blocked until `res.send('done')` gets called?

Comment: Your last statement is correct. Each middleware must either call next() or one of the response-ending methods, or the endpoint will hang.

Comment: but a setTimeout doesn't consume CPU ..